# Hybrid sql/nosql data store in Django for document-based fields?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, nosql

I am creating an application that needs to allow users to create custom fields, which I think would be best stored in a document-based (basically a serialized dictionary) model field.

I am concerned that I would run into performance issues storing these potentially very large documents in a SQL database, so I thought instead of storing the documents in the SQL database, I would just store pointers in the SQL database to the documents. The documents themselves would then be stored in a separate NoSQL database.

Assuming this structure makes sense, what is the best way to go about constructing a field that stores custom data fields in this manner? Optimally, these custom fields would be accessible on the object as attributes and would be denoted as custom with a "_c" appended to the name. E.g. created_date would become created_date_c on the django model object. I'm thinking custom managers would be best to tackle this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/

EDIT: My SQL database is MySQL. Also, documents could make more sense as columns (as e.g. in Cassandra). Thoughts on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no best approach to this task, but I advise you to look into two other options, that has its own pros and contras:

- Store your user defined data in a [JSONfield](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field) or [pickled field](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1694/). This will save you a lot of efforts in writing custom managers and NoSQL. If you are worried about storing it along with your fixed structure data, store it in a separate model with one-to-one relationship in a [separate InnoDB file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) for example.
- Store yours user data in a generalized `(field_id, field_name, content_type)` and `(object_id, field_id, field_value)` dictionaries. They can be split by field types (i.e. `int`, `string`, `float` etc.). This approach won't give you well performing data model from scratch, but smart indexing and [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html) can make it worth noting. And your data query, model structure enforcement will be alot easier from other approaches.
- If you consider using NoSQL or other db for your mutable content, be sure to choose one that has means for your data efficient querying, see [this discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/95606/is-there-a-simple-flat-xml-based-query-able-data-storage-solution) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_database#XML_Databases_with_database_APIs_.28XQJ.2C_XML%3aDB.2C_RESTful.29).